# DataGrid.GroupStyle container using GroupBox (or any other control) wont display binded data in its header

Tags: c#, wpf

I cannot get my bindings to work with a GroupBox.HeaderTemplate.

Context:

1. The GroupBox is declared inside a DataGrid.GroupStyle.
2. The DataGrid is declared inside a DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate.
3. The items source for the grouping is from a CollectionViewSource declared in XAML.
4. The bindings is a enum value.

   ```
           <DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
           <DataTemplate>
               <materialDesign:ColorZone>
                   <materialDesign:ColorZone.Resources>
                       <CollectionViewSource x:Key="TrimEdges" 
                                             IsLiveFilteringRequested="True"
                                             IsLiveGroupingRequested="True"
                                             Source="{Binding Domain.TrimLoopSet.Edges}"
                                             Filter="TrimEdges_OnFilter">
                           <CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
                               <PropertyGroupDescription PropertyName="TrimLoopOwner.Index"/>
                           </CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
                       </CollectionViewSource>
                   </materialDesign:ColorZone.Resources>

                   <!-- The DataGrid showing the ceiling openings -->
                   <DataGrid
                       SelectionMode="Extended"
                       SelectionUnit="FullRow"
                       AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                       RowValidationErrorTemplate="{x:Null}"
                       ColumnHeaderStyle="{StaticResource CustomDataGridColumnHeaderStyle}"
                       RowDetailsVisibilityMode="Visible"
                       Margin="0 0 0 10"
                       ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource TrimEdges}}">

                       <DataGrid.GroupStyle>
                           <!-- Style for groups at top level. -->
                           <GroupStyle>
                               <!-- Style for groups at top level. -->
                               <GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                                   <Style TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                                       <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,0,5"/>
                                       <Setter Property="Template">
                                           <Setter.Value>
                                               <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                                                   <GroupBox Margin="5 2.5"
                                                             materialDesign:ColorZoneAssist.Mode="Custom"
                                                             materialDesign:ColorZoneAssist.Background="{StaticResource BorderGreyColorBrush}"
                                                             Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignCardGroupBox}">

                                                       <GroupBox.HeaderTemplate>
                                                           <DataTemplate>
                                                               <StackPanel 
                                                                   Orientation="Horizontal">
                                                                   <Label 
                                                                       Margin="0"
                                                                       Content="{Binding Path=OpeningCategory, Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource EnumStringConverter}}"/>
                                                               </StackPanel>
                                                           </DataTemplate>
                                                       </GroupBox.HeaderTemplate>

                                                       <GroupBox.Content>
                                                           <ItemsPresenter />
                                                       </GroupBox.Content>
                                                   </GroupBox>
                                               </ControlTemplate>
                                           </Setter.Value>
                                       </Setter>
                                   </Style>
                               </GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                           </GroupStyle>
                       </DataGrid.GroupStyle>

                       <DataGrid.Columns>
                           <!--The type Column -->
                           <DataGridTemplateColumn 
                               Header="TYPE" 
                               HeaderStyle="{StaticResource CustomDataGridColumnHeaderStyle}"
                               MinWidth="200">
                               <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                   <DataTemplate>
                                       <!-- The  Trim type ComboBox -->
                                       <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding TrimSystems}"
                                                 DisplayMemberPath="Name"
                                                 SelectedValue="{Binding TrimSystem}"/>
                                   </DataTemplate>
                               </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                           </DataGridTemplateColumn>

                           <!--The HEIGHT Column -->
                           <DataGridTemplateColumn 
                               Header="HEIGHT" 
                               HeaderStyle="{StaticResource CustomDataGridColumnHeaderStyle}"
                               MinWidth="110">
                               <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                   <DataTemplate>
                                       <!-- The trim height TextBox -->
                                       <TextBox 
                                           Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignTextBox}"
                                           materialDesign:TextFieldAssist.SuffixText="{Binding Height.DisplayName}"
                                           Text="{Binding Height.Value}"/>
                                   </DataTemplate>
                               </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                           </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                       </DataGrid.Columns>
                   </DataGrid>
               </materialDesign:ColorZone>
           </DataTemplate>
       </DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
   ```

I've tried everything I can think of, including all the relative sources. I simply can't get it to work.

A hard coded value works fine so its just the binding.